# Able to flag comments on locked posts?

Tags: bug, comment-flags, locked-questions, locked

I went to upvote [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277407/do-we-want-hats#comment119836_277407), which is on a [locked post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277407/do-we-want-hats), and I received this error message: "This comment is not eligible for voting or flagging"

[image]

I then went to flag it, and it let me flag it. I also tested another comment with a different flag reason other than "other:needs mod attention" and that worked as well.

[image]

I don't think you're suppose to be able to flag comments on locked posts. So it's probably a bug that I was able to.

If for some reason this is by design now, then the error message should be updated by just removing the "or flagging" part.